# YII framework: zii.widgets.jui.cjuidialog fixed position

Tags: php, yii

Does anyone know if the zii.widgets.jui.cjuidialog (its a dialogbox) so does it have an option that is fixing its position, so it cant be moved, i know u can make the size fixed. But i dont like the fact that i can be moved. Any one got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CJuiDialog can have any options of [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). So, I think in your case you need to declare `draggable` option as `false`.

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id'=>'mydialog',
    'options'=>array(
        /* Other jQuery dialog options */
        'draggable' => false,
    ),
));
```

Comment: no, dragable doesnt seem to work.EIDT: Its draggable. Thank you it works.